# Implicitly add methods to constructor's prototype in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following is a code snippet from *Crockford's JavaScript: The Good Parts*:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this;
};
```

Crockford goes onto explain that

> "By augmenting Function.prototype with a method method, we no longer
>   have to type the name of the prototype property. That bit of ugliness
>   can now be hidden."

I'm basically at a loss to understand this point.  What did we have to do before that we no longer have to do now?

Comment: Touching the prototype of something you don't own is a terrible idea (you open the door to all kinds of conflicts). This is a astoundingly ill-advised bit of laziness on Crockford's part.

Comment: The "improvement" being made there is not really of much practical importance; I think it's more of a teaching example.

Comment: @ssube: Crockford "ill-advised"? meh. if it's a problem, show us instead of telling us...

Comment: @dandavis, if everyone's going to touch the `prototype` of an object she's not implementing, since you can do that *anywhere* in the code, it's very likely other people won't be aware of that edit. Say that at line 742, someone writes `String.prototype.toLowerCase = String.prototype.toUpperCase;` Sooner or later something odd happens, and hackers who will debug it won't suspect that errors come from expecting a different behaviour from  `String.prototype.toLowerCase`... Course, just my 2 cents.

Comment: It is considered best practice to not modify native objects' prototypes because it may create naming conflicts in the future if a new method or property with the same name is added

Comment: @ssube this is from a book published in 2008. His guidance has changed significantly since then.

Comment: @giuscri: i always find examples a bit contrived, but point made better than just saying so. if you dig back far enough, Doug put out some stuff that modified Object.prototype, so he's not flawless by any means. Still it depends on what you're doing and who's writing the code. I do think in some cases modifying Function.prototype and Array.prototype can be really handy, and if it's for a node box running your own custom code, you shouldn't have "surprises" anyway...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's saying that instead of writing:

```
MyType.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    ..
};
```

you can write this:

```
MyType.method("myMethod", function() {
    ...
});
```

with the possibility (given the `return this`) of dot-chaining another call:

```
MyType.method("method1", function() {
    ...
}).method("method2", function() {
    ...
});
```

Meh.

Answer (score 2):

Code break down:

```
Function.prototype.method
```

Every object in JavaScript allows *prototypes*. It's JavaScript way of inheritance. Function is the `master object` from which all other functions are created. When you set a prototype on it all Function objects inherit that property. In this case the function `method`.

```
 Function.prototype.method= function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this;
 };
```

If you wanted the expand your own `functions` with other methods you need to type:

```
  somefunction.prototype.name = function(){}
```

With this method you can do just this:

```
  somefunction.method(name, function)
```

This funky bit does that:

```
  this.prototype[name] = func;
```

It refers to the Function object using the `this` keyword. The proceeds to the prototype for inheritance. Sets the function to the prototype using `[name]`. This converts the string name to a property. Why so? Because:

```
 this.prototype.name
```

would not work properly. If you use the code above, every time a new `method` is added it will be referenced by `name` and not the name you'sve chosen.

Why is `prototype[example]` the same as prototype.example. Because in JavaScript every property is stored in a arrayish list on the object and can be called like you call an item from an array using Object[].

Answer (score 1):

***Lets prove corckford's statement:***

> "By augmenting Function.prototype with a method method, we no
>   longerhave to type the name of the prototype property. That bit of
>   ugliness can now be hidden."

Here crockford wanted to say you can manipulate ***Function.prototype*** to achieve many different functionality for your personal usage.It is a functionality added to the function.prototype to add new method/property to any function.Functions in javascript inherits form Function.prototype.lets break down your code.

> Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {

in this line Function.prototype is added a new method.This method receive two arguments.`name` satands for a new methods name .And `func` stands for its functionality.I think you are familiar with what is methods and properties are.Functions are first class object in javascript.So they can be added new properties and methods during runtime.

> this.prototype[name] = func;

Here ***this*** refers to the function which calls it.`[name]` is method name and `func` is the method's functionality It adds a new method to ***passed function*** using [array notation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) Then finally

> return this;

with this statement ***passed function*** is returned with a new method added to it.

***Here i have a practical example for you:***

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
this.prototype[name] = func;
return this;
};

function Myfunction(){       // a constructor function called Myfunction
    this.name='robin';      // it has a name property
}

Myfunction.method('mymethod',function (){ console.log(' i am available')});  //adds a method named 'mymethod to Myfunction constructor

var newObj=new Myfunction();     // creates a new instance  of Myfunction class
console.log(newObj.mymethod());  //calls mymethod() of newObj
```

Here `myfunction` is a constructor.We can add inherited methods to this constructor's prototype usind `Myfunction.prototype.mymethod=function(){ ..}`

If you use myfunction as a ***constructor*** this is the way you add method to it.But As  you've added  a new functionality  to ***Function.prototype***,you can simply call it like

```
Myfunction.method('mymethod',function (){console.log('i am available'}); //it will add a method named mymethod to Myfunction's prototype
```

This statement will add a new method called `mymethod` to `Myfunction()'s prototype` ***implicitly***.

so you ***don't*** have to write `Myfunction.prototype.mymethod=function(){ console.log('i am available');` .Instead you can write `Myfunction.method('mymethod',function (){ console.log('i am available'});`

So it proves it will relieve you from  writing `Myfunction.prototype` again and again every time you want to add new methods to ***Myfunction constructor***.

So it proves ***crockford's statement .***